# How to construct PDOStatement class?

Tags: php, pdo

I am writing a PDO extension. I would like `prepare` method of `PDO` to not call upon its parent and instead construct the `PDOStatement` of its own.

```
class Foo extends \PDO {
    public function prepare ($statement, $driver_options = []) {
        // return parent::prepare($statement, $driver_options);
        // What does parent::prepare do?
    }
}
```

It appears that PDO `prepare` method simply constructs `PDOStatement` instance, but then `PDOStatement` constructor does not have all the parameters that I would expect there (the statement itself, etc).

How to write PDO `prepare` method in user-land?

Note that I am aware about the presence of the `PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS` and that it can be used to name the `PDOStatement` class to construct. I am interested whether that `PDOStatement` can be constructed in the user-land.

Comment: Hi Gajus, what is user-land.

Comment: @meda, user-land is an informal term for "written in PHP code instead of in C code."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't instantiate a PDOStatement directly. It's hard-coded to disallow it.

I find this in the PHP 5.5 source, in ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c:

```
static PHP_FUNCTION(dbstmt_constructor) /* {{{ */
{
        php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_ERROR, "You should not create a PDOStatement manually");
}
/* }}} */
```

You should create a PDOStatement by calling PDO::query() or PDO::prepare().

It's not clear from your question *why* you would need to instantiate a PDOStatement directly. I think you need to rethink your goals.